# M-x command cannot run

Tags: emacs24

I met a problem after reinstalling emacs24 and update the installed packages, that the command M-x cannot execute any command, for example, M-x shell.
There is an error message:

Wrong number of arguments: execute-extended-command, 2

Can any one can help me to figure out this problem?

Comment: Does this happen if you run `emacs -q`? if not, there's a problem in your `.emacs` file.

Comment: This is also happening to me after I updated my packages. For me, `smex` is throwing the above error and uninstalling it removes the problem but it also breaks my ido mode.

Comment: Which package archive(s) are you using? Things may have broken when I started using MELPA and then upgraded earlier today - it's likely an untested version of a package in MELPA is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the above replies. The problem indeed caused by the package from MELPA update. Problem solved after removed the package.

Comment: I have the same problem. What package was that?